# Find last used cell in column and populate the cell following

Tags: excel, vba

I am populating a spreadsheet using VBA. This VBA writes a formula to the last row, but is formatted not to give 0 values, so will only populate if it has anything greater than 1.

Let's say it copies down 100 rows, how do I find the last dynamic row, but then populate the row below it?.

It is a totals line. I can copy down, but can't determine the end row and how to populate it.

Everything I have found gives me the last row, but it doesn't tell me how to use that info within VBA.

Example-
If A1:A100 = 1
A101 = Total 100

```
Sub ButtonMacroLatest()
'Hide alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'
' Macro8 Macro
'

'Save to users device
    ChDir "U:\WINDOWS"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="U:\WINDOWS\OrderForm.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

'Create new workbook and populate
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MSG"
    Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[1]C"
    Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[1]C[3]"
    Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "1400008000"
    Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "501346009175"
    Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
    Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "=Now()"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-x-systime]h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "HDR"
    Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "C"
    Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R4C2"
    Range("G2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[1]C[3]"
    Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R2C4"
    Range("K2").FormulaR1C1 = "STD"
    Range("L2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R5C2"
    Range("N2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R7C2"
    Range("O2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R8C2"
    Range("Q2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R9C2"
    Range("R2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R12C2"
    Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "POS"
    Range("B3").FormulaR1C1 = "=Row()*10-20"
    Range("C3").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[15]C[3]"
    Range("D3").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[15]C[1]"
    Range("E3").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[15]C[2]"
    Range("F3").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[15]C[5]"
    Range("G3").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[15]C[7]"
    Range("H3").FormulaR1C1 = "GBP"
    Range("L3").FormulaR1C1 = "TRA"
    Range("M3").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[-3], ""POS"")+COUNTIF(C[-3], ""HDR"")"

'Fills column to last row of data from Cell C15
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Range("C15:C" & LastRow).FillDown
    Range("D15:D" & LastRow).FillDown
    Range("E15:E" & LastRow).FillDown

    'Preformat cells to remove 0 value
    Range("A1:Z1000").Select
    Range("Z1000").Activate
    Selection.NumberFormat = "#;#;"

'Finds the last non-blank cell on a sheet/range.
Range("C" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[15]C[7]"

'Reinstate alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
MsgBox "We have saved a copy of your order form to your computer at C:\X\X"
End Sub
```

I have tried the advice given but it doesn't populate anything. Granted I have changed this slightly to reference another sheet.

The rows that copy down C:E are numeric part numbers. The total at the bottom will now be for the number of populated rows. How would I do this?. Sorry to move the goalpost, it only came up in conversation in a meeting I've just come out of.

Comment: Please share the code you are using. It's not immediately clear why you can't determine or populate the last row.

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Comment: It's wortyh noting an oddity which someone will probably explain easily. Note the line of code "Range("D3").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[15]C[1]". You would expect to see in D3 the contents of C15 from orderform.xlsx. However when you check the formula it enters it refers to F18??? This is the same for the other ones that copy down???? Not the foggiest why.

Comment: I think you mean E18. This is a relative reference so 15 rows down and 1 column to the right. Starting in D3 that takes you to E18.

Comment: SJR, ok so in laymans terms, break that down for me. My understanding is that D3 = R15C1 (A15) from order form.xlsx. But you are right, it is E18, so how come it starts from the cell being populated instead of just pulling through from the correct cell in the original form?. Happy to go to chat if needed. Also worth noting that if these referrences are not relative they don't populate down, hence being as they are.

Comment: R15C1 is A1 and static, but R[15]C[1] is relative - the square brackets signify this. It is relative to where the formula is placed, just as on a worksheet if you use RC notation (I don't). If you want C15 from a formula in D3 you need r[12]c[-1].

Comment: Can you use @SJR and then I am notified of your response? Also you have an answer below.

Comment: @SJR yeah no worries. As mentioned previously the below answer doesn't work.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a helpful description.

Comment: I didn't re type it as I have already explained what it did once, and that was simply nothing. It didn't highlight the cell, or give any indication of which was the last cell in the column. Very literally it made no change what so ever. I

Answer (score 2):

`Range("A" & LastRow)` where `LastRow` is a variable containing the last row in question (100 in your example)

For the line below it: `Range("A" & LastRow + 1)`

For the sum: `Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(A1:A" & LastRow & ")"`